# Excel VBA, paste special :- extended

Tags: vba, excel

A follow on from my last question.

I have working code :-

```
Sub copy()
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A19:B19").copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(4, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

and learned a lot more on VBA and kinda fun to use in excel aha.
question is this

In sheet1 I have added to the range, Cell style "good" and some vlookups to help with data pull back from different places within the workbook, when testing the above code, it copies the cells but also copies the vlookup, which return nothing.

Now I have tested it with the macro recorder, and it brings back with

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
        , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

the above does what I want it to do, but need some help to clean it up and make it work with the code which I already made.

can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: So just to check, you want it to paste with the `xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme` & `xlPasteValues` only?

Comment: Yes, and keeping the End(xlUp).Offset(4, 0) as part of the code, any hints ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to paste each time sperately

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A19:B19").copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(4, 0)
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End WIth

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Paste using `xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme` first as that will put in the formula and then `xlPasteValues` to remove the formulas

If the vlookup still doesn't enter the value then `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` before the code runs and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` after will stop the formulas from updating and should keep the values you want

Comment: that's does want I want it to do, but it removes the formatting, as in the cell style, any way to keep that

Comment: @halo_4 It should keep the format of the cell, thats all `xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme` does. The cell formatting, is this done through Conditional Formatting or just something that was done manually?

Comment: It was done manually, the cell style is "good" so it highlight a light green, which makes data easier to read. the keyboard shortcut for I want it to do is Ctrl + E

Comment: @halo_4 `.Style = "Good"` Will put in the good style you want, but if its not doing it from the copy and paste then there might be something interfering with the VBA/copy&paste. I tried it on my PC, Excel 2010 and it worked fine. You would put `.Style = "Good"` inbetween the `With` & `End With`